# Playing sound file from a live audio feed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I am looking to make a sound visualizer with Unity3D (mainly for the UI and graphics), and as I get ready to export the project, I need to know how to get a live audio feed from whatever is playing on the computer and translate that to the audio samples that my program uses.

Currently, I use preset .mp3 files and apply them to audiosources, and a script updates the samples live and those translate to the bars you see in audio visualizers. I would like to move this up a step, but I don't know how to do that. I've looked into NAudio and CSCore, but I haven't been able to make anything work.

All I need is for NAudio or CSCore to record to a file, and also have me continuously play that file. That seems like it would have problems though, so if I can just get a sound card stream and use that data to pass through to the program, that would be great.

If anyone has any experience, docs, or tips that can help me out, please send them over. Appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://opensebj.blogspot.nl/2009/04/naudio-tutorial-5-recording-audio.html

Comment: So, could I use this to not only record a file, but also play it immediately after? I don't just need to record audio, I need the stuff being played at the immediate interval to be translated. The article seems more directed towards recording